# Obj model losing transparency in Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, .obj

I am new to Scenekit. I was trying to load an .Obj model with its .mtl. Everything looks good only the transparent window glasses are appearing in solid sky-blue. While the same model in .dae format works perfectly. I tried to load the same .obj model in 3js and it worked as expected.

```
scnScene=SCNScene(named: modelPath)
```

What should I do to make the transparency work?